# Buscar registros de uma data a Outra

Tags: mysql, sql

A empresa tem o fechamento base de "21 a 20" de cada mês.
Gostaria de saber como faço para que o SQL busque apenas os registros que estão dentro do fechamento? Ex: meu fechamento deste mes é: 21/05 a 20/06, mas não quero pegar dos ultimos 30 dias... preciso que busque os registros dentro de um determinado periodo.

Comment: select * from tbl_t1 where data between inicioTeuPeriodo and fimTeuPeriodo.

Comment: Ainda não ficou muito claro o que você está querendo perguntar, você quer os registros que estão entre o dia 21/05 e 20/06 (por exemplo)? Ou você quer alguns dias específicos dentro desse intervalo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

André, criei um exemplo no SqlFiddle pra você dar uma olhada aqui.

### [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/852c47/2/0)

Neste exemplo, criei uma tabela de exemplo `tb_exemplo` e inseri 4 valores:

- Valor 1, Data '2015-05-19'
- Valor 2, Data '2015-05-21'
- Valor 3, Data '2015-06-10'
- Valor 4, Data '2015-06-22'

Para procurar por intervalos o ideal é utilizar o operador [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), até poderia fazer um `data > x and data < y`, mas é desnecessário já que possuímos outra opção.

Não sei se você vai trabalhar esses dados DEPOIS do `SELECT` então provavelmente você vai precisar da função [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://blog.tiagopassos.com/2010/03/17/formatar-datas-usando-o-date_format-do-mysql/) para exibir a data da forma que você precisa.

Exemplo citado no SqlFiddle:

```
SELECT *,date_format(campo_data,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` FROM tb_exemplo
WHERE campo_data BETWEEN '2015-05-21' AND '2015-06-20'
```

Saída

```
valor campo_data              data_formatada

2     May, 21 2015 00:00:00   21/05/2015

3     June, 10 2015 00:00:00  10/06/2015
```

### UPDATE

-

### [SqlFiddle Demo #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/852c47/9/0)

```
SELECT *,date_format(campo_data,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` FROM tb_exemplo
WHERE (DAY(NOW()) < 21 && campo_data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-21') as DATE), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                                         AND CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-20') as DATE))
   OR (DAY(NOW()) >= 21 && campo_data BETWEEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-21') as DATE)
                                         AND DATE_ADD(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-20') as DATE), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

#### Explicação

- `NOW()` - Retorna a data atual
- `DAY()` - Extrai o dia, então consigo saber se passou do dia 21 ou não
- `DATE_SUB()` - Subtrair data, no caso eu passo `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`, ou seja, vou SUBTRAIR 1 mês.
- `DATE_ADD()` - Adicionar data, no caso eu passo `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`, ou seja, vou ADICIONAR 1 mês.

Comment: Bom dia. Então, não seria bem isso... com o BETWEEN dá pra fazer, mas, tipo... a empresa trabalha com fechamentos de 21 a 20, ou seja... dia 21 desde mês se inicia um novo fechamento. Ou seja, a data na pesquisa teria de mudar para 21/06 a 20/07... e assim por diante. Tem como fazer?

Comment: @AndréBaill Você quer criar um `SELECT` fixo sem passar parâmetros pra pegar sempre o fechamento atual?

Comment: Exatamente... não quero passar qual é o periodo, pois o periodo é sempre FIXO... ou seja, sempre fechamos de 21 a 20 de cada mês.

Comment: @AndréBaill Entendi, mas no caso hoje dia `11/06` você queria que ele pegasse o período de `21/04/2015 - 20/05/2015` ou `21/05/2015 - 20/06/2015`? E quando chegasse no dia `22` continuasse o mesmo ou pulava pro próximo fechamento?

Comment: 21/05 a 20/06... Quando chegar no dia 21, passará a ser: 21/06 a 20/07

Comment: @AndréBaill Feito!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24715/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-maicon-carraro).